# How to calculate rectangle topx, topy, bottomx, bottomy from circle area android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have Circle X,Y and radius for drawing a circle, now I want to calculate the rectangle co-ordinates from this circle x,y, radius of the circle. I need help from this.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Circle X,Y as in center coordinates or?

Comment: yep, center co-odrinates only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
topx = X - radius
topy = Y - radius
bottomx = X + radius
bottomy = Y + radius
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mention X and Y are center cordinates of circle then:-

```
topx = X - radius 
topy = Y - radius
bottomx = X + radius
bottomy = Y + radius
```